# Trace SQL Query in EF Code First

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First and I'd like to be able to record all the SQL queries generated by the DbContext. In Linq to sql there was a DB log and I can't seem to find it in EF. I could then drop them in a log or output it to the page.

I'm using the version 4.1.0.0 of the EntityFramework Assembly.

Comment: Does EF allow you to pass in a connection (rather than a string)? I know of ways if you can

Comment: (to put that in context, we do this tracing in all of the stackoverflow code, and we don't use .Log)

Comment: Marc do you use a custom Connection implementation that hooks up the logging?

Comment: yes - custom connection, command, reader, etc - and in the process of open-sourcing it

Comment: @Marc Gravel Let me know when you open source it I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: a bit overdue, but re my comment above: this is what miniprofiler is: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/ - or: "ITmeze got it right"

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet would be to use the [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/), although it's unfortunately not free.

You can also manually get the SQL it will generate by running a `ToString()` on the `IQueryable` itself, but that will have to be done on a per-query basis.

One final option is that if you are using MS Sql Server as your backend, you can load up the Sql Server Profiler (that comes with Sql Server Management Studio I believe) and log the sql statements from there.

Comment: The OP is in luck if he decides to purchase this profiler as the creator (Ayende) is getting married today and offering a 29% discount until June 1st. http://ayende.com/blog/8193/the-big-event-is-just-a-week-away

Comment: Well crap, I might have to finally purchase it now as well.  $100 off is a bit hard to turn down

Comment: I know about profiler tools.  I would like an in code solution that will give me output on the MVC web page itself.  I dont want to have to do it per query I would like a event on the context that will let me capture the query and log it.

Comment: @feanz - the code we use here does ***exactly*** that; it allows us to review the SQL live, in context, on every single request

Answer (score 1):

[Miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) a free alternative to entity framework profiler that will allow you to trace all sql queries made during web requests

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave it here.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    { Database.Log = Console.Write;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With tools like EF it becomes more important than ever to use the SQL Server Profiler, and it should be the primary tool used for this type of situations, if it was important when we actually wrote the queries it is even more important now that these tools build the queries for us, it's a must not only for debugging but also for optimization