# Entity Framework Code First 4.3 + Sql Log

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, logging

I can't manage to find a good way to log sql requests with EF Code First 4.3.1 (I'm using MySql).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Eric

Comment: do you want log sql statement generated from EF?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: Duplicate (among many others): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168569/trace-sql-query-in-ef-code-first

Answer (score 0):

You can get sql statement generated from EF in this way:

```
var query = from u in context.Users      // linq query
            select u;

var sql_statement = ((ObjectQuery<User>)query).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: Yes I know this method but it does not permit to get ALL the requests generated. For example, what about requests due to lazy loading, etc?